# Easy way to insert lines from one file to another

Tags: text-processing

I have two massive text files containing more than 10000 lines.

I need to make from them a new file that contains a line from each file.

```
File1 

  line a
  line b
  line c
```

```
File2

   line 1
   line 2
   line 3
```

output

```
New File

   line a
   line 1
   line b
   line 2
   line c
   line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`paste`** command:

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2 > result
```

- `-d'\n'` - use newline character `\n` as delimiter between corresponding merged items/lines

---

```
$ cat result
line a
line 1
line b
line 2
line c
line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '1; { getline <"file1" } 1' file2
line a
line 1
line b
line 2
line c
line 3
```

or, more verbosely,

```
$ awk '{ print; getline <"file1"; print }' file2
line a
line 1
line b
line 2
line c
line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file descriptors`

open two file descriptors and read from them

```
while read -r -u 4 l1 && read -r -u 5 l2 ; do
echo $l1
echo $l2
done 4<file1 5<file2 > new_file
```

[read man](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html)